# Subclass without entity core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have Medicaion Entity.

```
MedicationEntity
name
dose
weekdays    //in case of daily and monthly this is null
monthdays   //in case of weekly and daily this is null
frequencyType  //Daily or weekly or monthly
etc
```

I want to subclass this entity with weekly and monthly medication so i can use polymorphism.But i do not want to make entity for it.The reason for that is

I do not have extra attribute in these classes except the Weekly and Monthly medication have all attribute same but have one additional attribute, in Weekly i have weekdays and in Monthly i have mothday.In case of Daily medication i have to send null in weekdays and monthdays.So if i subclass and move these weekdays and monthdays attributes to weekly and monthly subclasses i am not able to send null to server in request as there is no known parameter for DailyMedication class.SO i kept these attribute in Medication entity.Now i want to subclass this entity for daily,weekly and monthly without having entity in core data model.As alloc init is not allowed on `NSManagedObject` how to get these entity object if i subclass them as they are not in core data model?

Is there any another way to do that? My main problem is to send null for weekdays and monthdays in server request and also i think there is no meaning to create empty entities in core data model.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, you are confusing classes and entities.  You can have multiple classes that represent the same entity.  You do not need multiple entities in the model.  However, even that would be overkill for the situation you are describing.

The model you have listed in your question is fine.  The `frequencyType` determines the state of the `Medication` object (btw, remove the word `Entity` it is redundant and against common practice).

Comment: thanks @Marcus for your reply.So are you saying that i should make another class say `MedicaionModel` and subclass it or are you saying that i can make subclass `MedicationEntity` but in this case how can i get object of my subclassses.I want to subclass because i want to divide work in subclasses.

Comment: I am saying that you **can** have multiple subclasses but **you** should not.  Your use case is simple enough that you should have **one** entity that has stateful information.  Just like the server is passing to you.  There is no need to have multiple entities or classes.

Comment: Hi @Marcus thanks but actually my use case is not that simple.I have lots of work to do like scheduling,syncing etc.Currently I have full of overloaded classes.Now i want to divide my medication class in to subclasses so i can divide work of Daily,Weekly,Monthly in their respective classes by `single responsibility`but problem is that how should i manage the entity as if i make separate class `MedcationModel` and another for `MedicationEntity` then i need to manage them seprately.But if i make subclass of `MedicationEntity` than i need to make empty entity for subclasses to get proper object.

Comment: Any subclass of `NSManagedObject` can represent an entity by implementing the `-initWithEntity: insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` properly.  However, without the deep knowledge and understanding of Core Data that goes with it, you are going to run into issues during design.  Given that the data is the same for all three, it does make sense for them to be a single stateful object and then internally to the object you would have private methods that respond based on the state.  Having three different object types is only going to cause issues and unnecessary complexity.

Comment: thanks a lot and i really appriciate your help and thanks for all your suggestions.I am struggling with this.Is there any other way by which i can subclass or divide my code.I really really need to divide my work in subclasses because there are lots and lots of if statements in my code because of this `frequencyType` which is making my project unstructured.Please help me with this and suggest any good solution.I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1):

You cant have `init:` method for **NSManagedObjects**, cuz they are related to entities in database. You can only create entity in database and get reference to her. If you need another entity, you should create her in your model.

Also, you can use two property: `days` and `repeatEvery`, which can be 7, 30, or anything else. Or you can have dictionary, `repeatEvery:1 = daily`, `repeatEvery:2 = monthly`, etc. and keep just code in `repeatEvery` property.

Comment: `NSManagedObject` subclasses most certainly can have init methods.  But they must call `-initWithEntity: insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` in their `super`.  Nothing is stopping a developer from having a subclass with a custom `-init...`.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra Thats actually what i said. init**WithEntity**, so you **MUST** have an entity in database, for do that.

Comment: No, that is not what you said.  You may have thought you said it but your answer made zero sense.  Are you the one who decided to vote down my correct answer as well?